# How to get request initiator with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer

I am trying to log all network requests in a page. My goal is to later filter for particular requests and check their initiator. The code below runs fine if I comment line 12 `const request_initiator = interceptedRequest.initiator();`. But the initiator is something really need. According to [puppeteer's docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.5.1&show=api-httprequestinitiator) I am calling it correctly.

Here is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    const results = [];
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
        const request_url = interceptedRequest.url();
        const request_method = interceptedRequest.method();
        const request_payload = interceptedRequest.postData();
        const request_initiator = interceptedRequest.initiator();
        results.push({
            request_url,
            request_method,
            request_payload,
            request_initiator
        })
        interceptedRequest.continue();
    });
    await page.goto('https://testurl.com');
    await browser.close();
    return results
})().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result)
});
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: interceptedRequest.initiator is not a function
    at /Users/test/Desktop/code/tagv2/tcv2/index.js:12:54
    at /Users/test/Desktop/code/tagv2/tcv2/node_modules/peteer/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:51:62
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (/Users/test/Desktop/code/tagv2/tcv2/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:51:43)
    at Page.emit (/Users/test/Desktop/code/tagv2/tcv2/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:72:22)
    at /Users/test/Desktop/code/tagv2/tcv2/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:143:100
    at /Users/test/Desktop/code/tagv2/tcv2/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:51:62
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (/Users/test/Desktop/code/tagv2/tcv2/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:51:43)
    at NetworkManager.emit (/Users/test/Desktop/code/tagv2/tcv2/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:72:22)
(node:22974) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:22974) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: What version of Puppeteer are you using?

Comment: @ggorlen I am using the latest version 13.5.1

Comment: Weird. This exact code works for me on Puppeteer 13.0.1 and 13.5.1. I get `request_initiator: { type: 'other' }` in the output. Node 17.4.0 and Windows in case that matters.